# C# How to show Database table's items in datagridview (SQL)

Tags: c#, sql

I have two combobxes and datagridview,in first combobox has written my database's names,when i select any database's name, in second combobox appears that database  table's name.I need when i select any table, it must show me that table's items in datagridview.For example i select Suren_Products database, in second combobox appears 3 tables' names,from there i select products table, then in datagridview must show me that table's items.

[image: This is my Form]

But in this case Whatever I select,in datagridview shows me only products items.Why?

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Model db;
    public SqlConnection conn;
    public SqlDataAdapter adapter;
    public DataSet ds;
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ConnectionString;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.db = new Model();
        DataSet ds = db.Get_Databases();
        cb1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        cb1.DisplayMember = "Database_Name";
    }

    private void cb1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string x = (cb1.SelectedItem as DataRowView).Row["Database_Name"].ToString();
        DataSet ds = cb1.SelectedItem as DataSet;
        ds = db.Get_Tables(x);
        cb2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        cb2.DisplayMember = "name";

    }

    private void cb2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Products", connStr);
        ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        dgv.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `select * from Products` selects rows from products table only.

Comment: "select * from " + cb2.SelectedValue

Comment: You should do `"select * from "+ cb2.Text`

Comment: it gives error, says Invalid object name "System.Data.DataRowView".

Comment: @Kevin The user would have to set the cb2.ValueMember property for that to work.